# Verify Equivalence Relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

> Find an example of three relations $R_{1}$,
>     $R_{2}$,
>    and $R_{3}$
>     on the set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
>     such that
>
> - $R_{1}$
>     is reflexive but not transitive,
> - $R_{2}$
>     is transitive but neither symmetric nor reflexive, and
> - $R_{3}$
>     is symmetric but not reflexive.

Solution

Let $R_{1} = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(4,5),(5,5)\}$. It is symmetric
 but not transitive because $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,3),(2,4),(3,5) \notin R_{1}$.

Let $R_{2} = \{(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(3,4),(4,5),(3,5)\}$. It is transitive
  but not symmetric because ${(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4)} \notin R_{2}$.

Let $R_{3} = \{(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(4,5),(5,4)\}$. It is symmetric
  but not reflexive because $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5) \notin R_{3}$.

Can anyone please check my solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- Your $R_1$ is actually transitive. To prevent this, try (for example) adding $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$, but not $(1,3)$.
- Your $R_2$ is not transitive, since $(2,3),(3,4) \in R_2$ but $(2,4) \notin R_2$. To fix this, take the transitive closure by adding $(2,4), (2,5), (1,4), (1,5)$.
- Your $R_3$ works.

Comment: Hi Adriano should i satisfy Reflexive and for transitivity i just have to see whats not in there that will make it transivity then conclude my answer?

Comment: You correctly made $R_1$ reflexive and $R_2,R_3$ not reflexive. My answer gave some suggestions to make $R_1$ not transitive and to make $R_2$ transitive.